# Different hashCode for the same string?

Tags: java, hashmap, passwords, client-server, hashcode

I have made a log-in screen and want to check the password that a client enters with passwords in a server's database. If their HashCodes match, the password is accepted. However, the HashCode I get when I write a password on the client screen is different to the HashCode of the received string (password) on the server side.

Does anybody know why? Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: You've misunderstood. You shoudln't be using `hashCode()` for this, you should be using a secure hash, and you should be getting the database to do the hashing and comparing.

Comment: If two (out of box) objects are equal, their hash codes will be as well. Thus, if you're seeing unequal hash codes, the associated Strings are not equal either. No way to tell how you got to this point without seeing some code. Anyways, as @EJP mentions, you shouldn't be testing passwords in this fashion.

Comment: Is the server receiving the same string that the client is sending?

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood.

1. You should be using a secure hash, not the`hashCode()` method.
2. You *must not* store the plaintext password in the database. You must store the hash.
3. You should be getting the database to do the hashing and comparison:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = MD5(?)
   ```

   If this query returns 1, the user and password exist. If it returns zero, they don't. Note also that you don't want to distinguish between wrong username and wrong password, as this is an information leak to the attacker. Test them both together as above.

Comment: What's wrong with doing the hashing in the application? (server-side)

Comment: @immibis Not much point in distributing functionality that could all be in the SQL.

Comment: SQL is capable of generating HTML; doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: You should be using a secure hash with a salt, not MD5. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/8340).

Comment: *"Not much point in distributing functionality that could all be in the SQL."* - One possible point would be to reduce load on the database server.  (Admittedly it is not a very convincing point in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

@EJP has pointed out (correctly) that you should be using a secure hash function not Java `hashCode` for this.

> However, the HashCode I get when I write a password on the client screen is different to the HashCode of the received string (password) on the server side.

That is a puzzle.  If you are using `String.hashCode()` the only possible explanation is that you are hashing different strings; e.g. there could be leading / trailing white-space in one and not the other, or maybe one was hashed with a "seed" added to it.  I guess, another possible explanation could be that you are hashing a `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`, `char[]` or something else.